# Strange problem with highcharts heatmap - incorrect Y-axis scaling

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I ran across a very strange issue with a particular heatmap that I constructed using the Highcharts library.

I created a fiddle, where you can see the issue.

Here it looks ok: https://jsfiddle.net/gczea6t7/

However, if you try adding a new point, which in this case should be something like [3,33,50] in the data array (in the format x-coord, y-coord, value) it becomes completely messed up, the Y-scale creates some extra values. No matter what I add, even if I add eg. [5,33,20] it will still do this.

The problematic line starts with

```
     data: [[0,0,86.18],
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, in case someone encounters the same issue it is due to the turbo threshold value being set to 1000 as default, exceeding this number of points causes this issue.

Solution:

Add to your series properties turbo threshold value higher than 1000 or set it to 0 to disable this:

```
    turboThreshold: 0
```